# c# NullReferenceException but everything looks ok

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nullreferenceexception

i'm working on a school project and I got this error: NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code

Code:

```
private MazeGen mazeGen;

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        object[] args = e.Argument as object[];

        int value = (int)args[0];
        bool solving = (bool)args[1];

        if (!solving)
        {
            this.mazeGen.generateMaze(this.box.Width / value,
                (this.box.Height - value) / value);
        }
        else
        {
            this.mazeGen.solve();
            this.hasSolution = true;
        }
        this.box.Invalidate();
    }
```

So the error occurs in this part: "this.mazeGen.generateMaze(this.box.Width / value,
                    (this.box.Height - value) / value);"

The object mazeGen is nog an object. I already checked everything and the class mazeGen is also public so I really don't understand why the program can't find mazeGen. Also I checked if value, width and height had a value and they did.

Maybe it's a stupid solution but I really have no idea what it could be.

Comment: *Use the debugger, Luke!* Is `mazeGen` null?

Comment: Tengential, but you're using a safe cast so you should be checking for  `args == null`.  Otherwise there is no point in using the save cast to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

Simply, you are not initializing the `mazeGen`, so it's null.

```
private MazeGen mazeGen = new MazeGen();
```

Comment: I think I got the problem now! Thanks for you answer. So stupid always when I asked a question I get more inspiration ><